# Moving a doorbell transformer

Tags: doorbell

Can a doorbell transformer that is on the outside of a wall be place inside the wall behind the drywall. I’m concerned about it getting too hot. Mine is in the kitchen by the ceiling lights[image]

Comment: Usually these transformers are in a closet. This appears to be in the open and is not attractive to put it mildly. I would see if you can get a removable box to cover it which has a grille on bottom or at least is open on the top.

Comment: it should not get hot, except maybe on Halloween. jk, it should never never get hot; they don't do much work.

Comment: So it sounds like it would be ok to put behind the wall with a plate over the opening?  Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

The door bell transformer is mounted to a mains electrical box. Electrical code requires that all electrical boxes remain accessible. You cannot bury or hide an electrical box.

This translates to the fact that you cannot cover the electrical box + transformer behind drywall.